# reactjs: using `if else` in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, fetch-api, stateful

I'm having trouble with this (simple?) goal.

On the react show page, I would like under the "Instrument Section(s)" heading an unordered list of the student's instrument sections, which is easy enough.  The async setting of state works, and in the render I use:

```
let instrumentList = this.state.instrumentSections.map((instrument)=>{
  return <li>{instrument}</li>;
});
```

and in the relevant part of the return I use:

```
<h3>Your section(s):</h3>
          <ul>{instrumentList}</ul>
```

The trouble comes when the student is not assigned to any instrument section yet (so the state is set to `[]`).  I would like to display "Instrument Section(s)" and then "You are not yet part of a band." instead of "Instrument Section(s)" and then nothing, which is what happens with the above code.

I've tried using `if then` in several ways (one shown below, slight variations attempted to the same effect), but no matter what I try, the information displays correctly for a student with assigned instrument sections but continues to display "Instrument Section(s)" and then nothing.  If I `console.log(instrumentList)` in this case, it returns `[]`.

if then in render:

```
let instrumentList;
    const noBand = "You are not part of a band yet.  Please make sure that your instructor adds you to the right band through Ensemble.";
    if (this.state.instrumentSections !== [] ) {
      instrumentList = this.state.instrumentSections.map((instrument)=>{
        return <li>{instrument}</li>;
      });
    } else {
      instrumentList = noBand;
    }
```

Do I need to try working this `if then` magic in a `.then` of the async fetch?  Other ideas?

**Update Edit 3/12:**

I'm playing around with everyone's suggestion.  I see what the inline conditional operator's supposed to do, but I haven't been able to adapt it to my code the way CocoHot has refactored it due to (I think) the placement of `return`.

So here's the refactoring included with the `return` for the whole `class`:

```
render(){
  const noBand = "You are not part of a band yet.  Please make sure that       your instructor adds you to the right band through Ensemble.";
  const instrumentList = this.state.instrumentSections.map((instrument)=>{
    <li>{instrument}</li>;
  });
  return instrumentList.length > 0 ? instrumentList : noBand;

  return (
      <div className="text-center student-show">
        <h1>{this.state.student.first_name} {this.state.student.last_name}</h1>
        <h3>Your section(s):</h3>
          <ul>{instrumentList}</ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I'm rather sure the main problem in the above is that the `render` can't have more than one return, which I think means that I have to work the conditional operator line into the second `return` and get rid of the first `return`.  I've been trying to do so without success thusfar, so I've also tried working the operator line into the `const instrumentList =` block with no success.

Any more suggestions?  I know the solution is close, and thank you all for your help so far.

**Edit 2:** While trying to refactor into the vanilla `if else` format to see if things would work that way, I noticed the code wasn't returning `true` on the length check because it was set to `> 0` (so the empty array evaluated false).  I changed the operator to `== 0` and now it seems to trip correctly, at least in the vanilla format.  Still no luck on getting `noBand` to display.

Comment: instead of testing `!== []`, test the length `this.state.instrumentSections.length > 0` the reason being that a new instance of `[]` is not === an existing instance of `[]`. `[] === []` is `false`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Edit author's code to the proper way. Didn't test the code but should be able to get a big picture.

As Steven Stark mentioned in the comment, the right way to determine if a list is empty you should use `this.state.instrumentSections.length > 0` instead of `!== []`. 
Keep in mind that javascript's `if` compare is very dangerous.

You can use conditional operator to make your code simpler:

```
render() {
  const { student, instrumentSections } = this.state;
  return (
      <div className="text-center student-show">
        <h1>{student.first_name} {student.last_name}</h1>
        <h3>Your section(s):</h3>
          {instrumentList.length === 0 ? (
             <span>You are not part of a band yet...something more...</span>
          ) : (
             <ul>
               {instrumentSections.map((instrument) => {
                 return (<li>{instrument}</li>)
               })}
             </ul>
          )};

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I think it's a little incomplete to claim `if` in `js` are dangerous w/o giving proper explanation to why. If you're referring to type coercion then can you mention that or any other reason you think of as such?

Comment: I've tried implementing the collective suggestions, CocoHot, but I can't quite get it to work.  I've updated the original post with progress and additional relevant info.